# Multiple Datacenters

Tags: python, mysql, replication, scaling

I am finding a lack of information regarding handling multiple datacenters.  What tools and techniques are available for taking advantage of multiple datacenters?  A requirement is that the databases become consistent very quickly.

Comment: Voting to close, though I suggest you take a look at massively distributed/parallel systems like Hadoop and BigTable

Comment: Try asking on http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: "handling" multiple datacenters?  What does "handling" mean?  "taking advantage"?  What does this mean?  What does "databases become consistent" mean?  What are you talking about?  Can you give an example?  Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-cluster.html
```